# Найти номер телефона по ID на Андроиде - как?

Tags: android

Есть приложение, по нажатию одной кнопки высвечивается имя контакта, а так же сохраняется ID контакта в базе телефона.

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_DATE) {
        Date date = (Date) data.getSerializableExtra(DatePickerFragment.EXTRA_DATE);
        mCrime.setDate(date);
        updateDate(getMyDateFormat());
    } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CONTACT && data != null) {
        Uri contactUri = data.getData();
        // Определение полей, значения которых должны быть возвращены запросом
        String[] queryFields = new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.Contacts._ID};
        // Выполнение запроса - contactUri здесь выполняет функции условия "where"
        Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contactUri, queryFields, null, null, null);
        try {
            // Проверка получения результатов
            if (c.getCount() == 0) {
                return;
            }
            // Извлечение первого столбца данных - имени подозреваемого.
            c.moveToFirst();
            String suspect = c.getString(0);
            String contactID = c.getString(1);
            getPhoneNum(contactID);
            mCrime.setSuspect(suspect);
            mSuspectButton.setText(suspect);
            enableCallBut();
        } finally {
            c.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Как мне достать номер контакта имея его ID? В нете видел что надо обратится к  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone но сам допереть не могу. Еще вопрос вдогонку про разрешения, какое надо и где именно в Манифесте его указывать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из разрешений нужно только это

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Зная `ID` контакта, вот так можно получить все его номера телефонов

```
val cur = ctx.contentResolver.query(
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
    arrayOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER),
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
    arrayOf("<ContactID here>"),
    null
)
```

Код на Котлине, но суть должна быть понятна.

Comment: Кидает исключение  Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/data/phones from pid=3572, uid=10083 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS, or grantUriPermission()

Comment: Свой манифест добавил в первый пост

Comment: Вы явно тестите на Андроид 6 или выше, отобрав разрешения у приложения, вручную как пользователь. Оттуда и ошибка.

Comment: Если не хотите заморачиваться с `runtime permissions`, потавить в проекте `targetSdkVersion 22`.